# Insert created date(now) and created by(username) in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Please anybody help me to Insert created date(now) and created by(username) in asp.net5.
whenever I create the new record in crud application the above records should be entered automatically in database.

regards arun sahani

Comment: You can set DEFAULT value to GETDATE() for CreatedDate column in your table; you may need to pass user name from your UI with other parameters you are already passing

Comment: from database table point of view getdata() is ok.

Comment: I want to get this done from asp.net mvc 5 controller and view

Comment: As pointed out this is not solved by asp.net. It can probably be solved in your database layer. Do you use Entity Framework or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing to do with MVC or any technology.  You will have to either pass these values from UI or use SQL Default values to populate

```
CreateUserId nvarchar(55) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_CreateUserId] DEFAULT suser_sname()
```

Use `suser_sname` only in those cases where you perform your operations from UI to DB with the logged-in user credentials.  In most of the web apps, it is not the way, so you may end up passing the actual your name or your user id to database like any other fields you pass for that table.

For timestamp, you can fairly use this Default value

```
CreateDateTime DateTime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

This will automatically populate created time stamp whenever you insert values into that table.  You don't need to pass any value for this column while inserting.  You can optionally pass value, if you want to insert some other value from UI.

Let us say for example, you don't set DEFAULT values in fields; you can certainly pass values from UI to populate those fields; What happens when someone inserts a row directly into table without going through UI Process? May be a an Admin inserting a row?  You need to consider all those scenarios.