# Entity Framework : Create/Update common field in multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am using EF and ASP.NET MVC for my website. All the tables in the database has two fields

LastModifiedBy - Logged In User Name

LastModifiedDate - Today's date and time

Can I write some code at a single place which will input these values into the tables while their rows were created or updated?

Comment: You can refer [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922291/insert-created-datenow-and-created-byusername-in-asp-net-mvc-5/36922595#36922595) posted on a separate question

Comment: @techspider Your answer is wrong in 2 ways though. First it does not account for the logged in user in the MVC app, instead it uses teh SQL user, probably from the connection string. Secondly, it will not update the last updated time, only the creation time.

Comment: I know that :)... I didn't want to use that answer as it is... Further, I added more points on that answer itself to consider various options :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. First make an interface that has the properties you need for user and time:

```
public interface IAudit
{
    DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And ensure that any entity that needs these properties is implementing it:

```
public class Car : IAudit
{
    //snip

    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()        
    {
        //Handle the SavingChanges event:
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.SavingChanges += objectContext_SavingChanges;
    }

    private void objectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = (ObjectContext)sender;

        context.DetectChanges();

        foreach (var entry in context.ObjectStateManager
                        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
        {
            if (entry.Entity is IAudit)
            {
                if (entry.IsRelationship) continue;

                var auditEntry = (IAudit)entry.Entity;

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    auditEntry.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                    auditEntry.UpdatedBy = GetUser();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the ValidateEntity method on your data context.  Below is an example:

```
public partial class YourDataContext
{
    protected override System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        if (entityEntry.Entity is Boat && entityEntry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified)
        {
            Boat modifiedBoat = (Boat)entityEntry.Entity;

            // Set your last modified date and other properties here
        }

        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My data context is deriving from ObjectContext not DbContext, so I can use this method.